# How to set up WebDAV (with wfsctl) on macOS High Sierra with Server 5.6.1?

Tags: high-sierra, osx-server, apache, proxy

After having upgraded to High Sierra with Server 5.6.1 I want to recreate the WebDAV shares I had. I've used wfsctl to create a share point. The share point has ACL for a specific user. So far so good and wfsctl lists the share, but since Server.app is configuring Apache (a web site is running too) something must be done to make it work. "The Apache http instance for WFS should be configured to run behind macOS Server's proxy." wfsctl diagnose says "Config is valid", btw.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

And ... I found the solution (so far).

The issue was that I did not use Wiki Server before on macOS Sierra + Server. Wiki Server was turned off. However, to enable WebDAV sharing on macOS High Sierra + Server, you need to activate Wiki Server in Server.app and turn WebDAV sharing on.

The tip was found on Tod Olthoff's blog: http://www.toddolthoff.com/blog_files/c6e4e39502d35b674693ad80ac2ca042-445.html

So, the only thing I had to do to get my wfsctl managed WebDAV shares running again was to turn Wiki Server on and WebDAV sharing on in Wiki Server.